# Watson speech to text: Invalid credentials error (Code: 401)

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to use the IBM Watson speech to text API/service in the following Python program.

```
import json
import os
import sys
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1

def transcribe_audio(audio_file_name) :
    IBM_USERNAME = "yourusername"  

    IBM_PASSWORD = "yourpassword"
    #what changes should be made here instead of username and password

    stt = SpeechToTextV1(username=IBM_USERNAME, password=IBM_PASSWORD)
    audio_file = open(audio_file_name, "rb")        
    json_file = os.path.abspath("america")+".json"; 
    with open(json_file, 'w') as fp:
        result = stt.recognize(audio_file,timestamps=True,content_type='audio/wav', inactivity_timeout =-1,word_confidence = True)
        result.get_result()
        json.dump(result, fp, indent=2)
    script = "Script is : "
    for rows in result['results']:
        script += rows['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
    print(script)
transcribe_audio("america.wav")
```

This code gave me an authentication error as mentioned in the title because IBM changed the authorization method from **username + password** to **apikey** 
very recently.

Could anybody tell me what changes should be made in this? 
And also how to generate the apikey on IBM Watson speech to text with username and password?

I am new to speech recognition, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **how to generate the api key on ibm watson speech to text with username and password?** You automatically get spikey . Check your [IBM Cloud console](https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps) and click on your service. But This apikey is not used for authentication for streaming audio.

Comment: Kindly go through [this documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/speech-to-text). Directly jumping over SDKs is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @RC0993 Thank you so much. I kinda figured out getting the api keys shortly after posting.

Comment: @RC0993 But the documentation link you mentioned was pretty useful and saved a lot of time.

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue, if yes can you post the answer here, it would be of great help as i am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Harshit Yadav  This thread is quite old. I resolved the issue and validated the answer as well. The answer is  pretty straightforward. You just have to read the documentation. That's it. It's well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information you want is in the API documentation, including how to obtain the API Key - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python